# Quotient group of normalizer N(K) with Sylow p-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am self studying from Pinter's "Abstract Algebra". Chapter 16, section M, question 5 has a question where we have to prove that no element of $N/K$ has order a power of $p$.

Let $K$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, and $N = N(K)$ the normalizer of $K$.

I use the correspondence theorem:

$$S \cong S^*/K$$

Where $S$ is the cyclic subgroup of $N/K$ generated by $Ka$.

$$S^* = \{ x \in N : Kx \in S \}$$

For any $x \in K$, then $Kx = K \in S$, so $x$ itself is in $S^*$. That means $K$ is a subgroup of $S^*$ but since $K$ is maximal, we conclude $S^* = K$ and for any $a \in N, Ka = K$.

Now my question is, does the correspondence theorem prove that $S = \{K\}$? If so we just proved no element of $N/K$ has order a power of $p$ (since it equals the whole group). If my logic is incorrect, then how should I approach this question?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier simply to note that since $K$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, it's necessarily also a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N$, so $p$ does not divide $\vert N/K \vert$ and $N/K$ can't have any elements of order $p$.

If any group has an element $g$ of order $ap, a \in \Bbb N$, then $g^a$ has order $p$.  Since $N/K$ can't have any such elements and any power of $p$ is also a multiple of $p$, $N/K$ can't have any elements with order a power of $p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. $K$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N$ because being a prime power, its elements behave like an abelian group and hence commute? Hence $p$ does not divide $|N/K|$.

Comment: Not at all.  $K$ need not be abelian.  $K \leq G$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup if and only if $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ whose order is the largest power of $p$ that divides $\vert G \vert$.  Since $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $K$, the largest power of $p$ dividing $\vert G \vert$ must also be the largest power of $p$ dividing $\vert N \vert$.

Comment: Right so $|G| = p^m t$ then $|N| = p^m s$ (where s divides t). And $|K| = p^m$ so $|N/K| = s$. Thanks a lot!